# Most efficient way to do an XSL transformation on a DataSet?

Tags: .net, xslt, dataset

What is most efficient way (code example) to do an XSL transformation on a DataSet in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked out pretty well performance-wise for me in the past:

http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000246.html

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to save the DataSet to XML, then you have a simple XML document that you can run the XSL on.

I use this all the time for doing Excel exports

Comment: I am concerned about the size of the XML document DOM (my DataSets can be rather large) when it's going to be loaded into memory for transformation, so I am trying to find a more efficient way of doing it.